# Use Process.StandardInput with Mono

Tags: c#, process, mono, graphviz, dot

I am trying to convert an existing Windows Form application to run on a Mac using Mono.  For the most part, the entire application is running as expected, with one exception.  Part of the application uses Graphviz to draw an output and generate a PDF, which works just fine on Windows.  However, when I run using Mono on my Mac, I get "System.IO.IOException: Write fault on path /Users/Kevin/Desktop/TitleChain/[Unknown]" (full stack trace below).  I've traced this back, I think, to the fact that Mono starts the process and it immediately exits before I can do a process.StandardInput.WriteLine to send the text of the dot file.  Not sure if there is something I can include in the ProcessStartInfo that will keep the process from exiting prematurely.  Maybe something using ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput/Output?

The code has no problem finding the dot.exe Graphviz executable and I have already overcome issues with permissions.  Everything points to Mono not realizing that the process needs to be kept open while I handle StandardInput and StandardOutput.

To give credit where credit is due, this code was originally adapted from graphvizwrapper: https://github.com/JamieDixon/GraphViz-C-Sharp-Wrapper

```
        var processStartInfo = this.GetProcessStartInfo(fileType);
        if (masterForm.IsRunningOnMono() || debugMode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running Mono, using alternative process methodology");                

            var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(dotFile);
            var baseStream = process.StandardOutput.BaseStream;

            output = this.ReadFully(baseStream);
        }
```

Functions used:

```
    private System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo GetProcessStartInfo(string returnType)
    {
        return this.getProcessStartInfoQuery.Invoke(new ProcessStartInfoWrapper
        {
            FileName = this.FilePath,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            Arguments = "-v -o -Tpdf",
            CreateNoWindow = true
        });
    }

    private byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            input.CopyTo(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

GetStartProcessQuery class:

```
    public Process Invoke(ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo)
    {
        return Process.Start(processStartInfo);
    }
```

The only other relevant information I can think to provide is that the initial application is located in and executed from the TitleChain folder, and the graphviz dot.exe is located in a subdirectory named "graphviz".

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Stack trace:

```
System.IO.IOException: Write fault on path /Users/Kevin/Desktop/TitleChain/[Unknown]

at System.IO.FileStream.WriteInternal (System.Byte[] src, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x00077] in <bb7b695b8c6246b3ac1646577aea7650>:0 

at System.IO.FileStream.Write (System.Byte[] array, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x00090] in <bb7b695b8c6246b3ac1646577aea7650>:0 

at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush (System.Boolean flushStream, System.Boolean flushEncoder) [0x0007e] in <bb7b695b8c6246b3ac1646577aea7650>:0 

at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write (System.Char[] buffer, System.Int32 index, System.Int32 count) [0x000d3] in <bb7b695b8c6246b3ac1646577aea7650>:0 

at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine (System.String value) [0x00070] in <bb7b695b8c6246b3ac1646577aea7650>:0 

at TitleChainApplication.GraphVizWrapper.GraphGeneration.GenerateGraph (System.String dotFile, TitleChainApplication.Enums+GraphReturnType returnType) [0x00103] in <5bfb1715358f4c24a3905e8d8ae55245>:0 

at TitleChainApplication.Form1.ExportTree (TitleChainApplication.Enums+GraphReturnType fileType) [0x00034] in <5bfb1715358f4c24a3905e8d8ae55245>:0 

at TitleChainApplication.Form1.ExportPDF () [0x00001] in <5bfb1715358f4c24a3905e8d8ae55245>:0 

at TitleChainApplication.Form1.pDFToolStripMenuItem_Click (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00001] in <5bfb1715358f4c24a3905e8d8ae55245>:0 

at TitleChainApplication.Form1.Export_ButtonClick (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00001] in <5bfb1715358f4c24a3905e8d8ae55245>:0 

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSplitButton.OnButtonClick (System.EventArgs e) [0x00019] in <84cef96c1ef54299a622b3e52fada5d0>:0 

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSplitButton.HandleClick (System.Int32 mouse_clicks, System.EventArgs e) [0x00028] in <84cef96c1ef54299a622b3e52fada5d0>:0 

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent (System.EventArgs e, System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemEventType met) [0x00054] in <84cef96c1ef54299a622b3e52fada5d0>:0 

at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(System.EventArgs,System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemEventType)

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp (System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs mea) [0x00048] in <84cef96c1ef54299a622b3e52fada5d0>:0 

at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmLButtonUp (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00078] in <84cef96c1ef54299a622b3e52fada5d0>:0 

at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x001b4] in <84cef96c1ef54299a622b3e52fada5d0>:0 

at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <84cef96c1ef54299a622b3e52fada5d0>:0 

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <84cef96c1ef54299a622b3e52fada5d0>:0 

at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <84cef96c1ef54299a622b3e52fada5d0>:0 

at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x0000b] in <84cef96c1ef54299a622b3e52fada5d0>:0 

at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (System.IntPtr hWnd, System.Windows.Forms.Msg msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) [0x00085] in <84cef96c1ef54299a622b3e52fada5d0>:0
```

Comment: Which version of Mono are you using?

Comment: I’m using 5.10.1.47.  Thanks.

Comment: No sure if these is related or not to your problem or not, as I had a related error (with Xamarin.Android) :  https://github.com/madelson/MedallionShell/issues/22 and the Mono bug that was filled (but the response did not deal with the issue that I actually had....) : https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/8417